# How AWS Glue job paramenter 'MaxConcurrentRuns' relate to the concurrent executions of the StepFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have a couple of StepFunctions staemachines that I want to run them concurrently, each of them will link to a Glue job, currently the `MaxConcurrentRuns` parameter for Glue job is set to the default value `1`, I understand this means we can only have only `1` Glue job running at the same time.

So for example, if I want to run `5` StepFunction statemachines at the same time, I can just set `MaxConcurrentRuns` parameter for Glue to `5` right? I also want to know how I can find out what's the service limit in general for this parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html -> Number of concurrent job runs per job = 1000. Funny that Number of concurrent job runs per account = 50...

Comment: I'm a bit confused by `Number of concurrent job runs per job`, my understanding is that if we kick off a job, it can't be kicked off again during the execution, that means for job it can be run concurrently, unless I missed something here...